# Integrity constraint violation in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

[image][image]I am passing the **ID** in URL to get to the **Form Page** I want but I want to pass in the same **ID** when I hit the submit button and I want to pass in the same **ID** to the database table name **"created_by"**

**Here's My Route:-**

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostsController@create');
```

**Here's My Controller:-**

```
public function create(){
  return view('Posts.CreatePost');

}

public function store(Request $request){
    post::create([
              'title'=>$request->title,
              'body'=>$request->body,
              'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'created_by' => $request->route('id'),
            ]);

    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

**Here's My Migration:-**

```
public function up(){
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('created_by');
            $table->string('filled_by');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

**Here's My Model:-**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{ protected $gaurded = [];

  protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'user_id', 'created_by', 'filled_by'];

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

The Error that i am getting is **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_by' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `user_id`, `filled_by`, `created_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (adsa, asdas, 1, 1, ?, 2020-04-16 20:54:30, 2020-04-16 20:54:30))**

I am just a beginner at programming and `laravel` so excuse me if I am being stupid

*-ThankYou*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `$request->route('id')` is empty and your database doesn't allow for the `created_by` column to be empty.

To debug, check the content of your request:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    // Die and dump the request:
    dd($request->all());

    post::create([
              'title'=>$request->title,
              'body'=>$request->body,
              'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'filled_by'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'created_by' => $request->route('id'),
            ]);

    return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

---

I believe you are not correctly retrieving the value `id` from the request.

You probably want to retrieve it with `$request->id` but it's hard to say without looking at your blade view. If you can share your view I'll edit my answer.

---

**Edit:** Also, your route is incorrect. To point to your controller `create()` method, you shouldn't have to pass an `id` to your route. By definition, you want to CREATE an object that doesn't yet exist and therefore doesn't yet have an ID.

With the create() method, your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostsController@create');
```

Also, if you want to follow Laravel naming conventions (trust me, you do), your controllers should be named in singular and url models in plural. Meaning it would look like this:

```
Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create');
```

And the route for your store() method should look like this:

```
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');
```

Comment: i just added the picture of it, i dont understand what am i looking for over here?

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox Please use `dd($request->all())`. I've edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: i've added the 2nd picture to my question

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox Thanks! What is the value of `created_by`? Is it supposed to be the `post_id` or the `user_id`?

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox Based on your first image, your request doesn't contain the `id` value you are trying to retrieve. It only contains `title` `body` and Laravel CSRF token. And with the create method, your route shouldn't contain an ID since by definition the model hasn't been created yet. I'm not sure what value you want `created_by` to contain but it's not in your request and it shouldn't be in your route.

Comment: my whole idea was to have a form hosted by an authenticated user and filled by another authenticated user, So i was trying to separate them by inserting their **ID** in the form by making **"created_by"** table for hosts **ID** and **filled_by** table for fillers **ID** in the form model. Do you have any other way to do this then please  do guide me  with it

Comment: Would it work it first user CREATE the post, and then later second user UPDATE the post? In this case you should allow your `created_by` column to be nullable in your migration, leave column empty during create and fill this column in the post update().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211834/discussion-between-anonymous-chatbox-and-lobsterbaz).